# Changing levels of dataframe column changes value in dataframe

Tags: r, categorical-data

I do not get this logic:

```
x_value <- "yes"
df <- data.frame(
                x = x_value
            )

levels(df$x) <- c("no", "yes")

df
```

This result in:

```
df
   x
1 no
```

So changed the value of x in the one row I originally created. When I assign levels to a factor column in the data-frame, is this not simply defining meta data?

How can I maintain the original value(s) - in this only one column with value = "yes" whilst assigning levels? Or should I create empty dataframe and assign levels and then values? Thanks!

My specific use case is that I have some value coming from somewhere (predictor values). So basically one row of data. I then want to make a prediction. Most R models require the levels to be set though. Hence, I do the above but it changes the data?!

PS:

I can do but it seems clumsy:

```
x_value <- "yes"
df <- data.frame(
                x = x_value
            )

levels(df$x) <- c("no", "yes")

df[1,]$x = x_value
```

PPS:

This may be the shortest code - thanks:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = factor(x_value, levels = c("no", "yes"))
)
```

Comment: Try `df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = c("no", "yes"))`

Comment: Let us know if the linked post helps.

Comment: @zx8754 I would not agree that the proposed link is the same context!

Comment: We are trying to add a new level. The way you tried is wrong, and that post explain the better way. "I don't get the logic" is not a question.

Comment: For me it is because levels are meta data AFIK and should not change actual values!

Comment: "Actual values" are integers, and they didn't change, it is 1. Check `as.numeric(df$x)`.

Comment: @zx8754: the linked post does **not** address this question here. And it is not just about adding a level to a factor. This question should not be closed because it "*already has an answer*". The other post is about something else.

Comment: @Georgery What do you think is the question here? I can see 4 "?" marks in the post.

Comment: @zx8754 I appreciate what you said reg. the value not changing but I would also say that the other linked question is not comparable to my one. I am happy I learned something and got my answer anyway ....

Comment: @zx8754: the question is "Why does `levels()` change the value?" This is a valid question.

Comment: @Georgery - I appreciate this and this is my point exactly. Unfortunately, people on SO are very trigger happy and have a bit of a hostile attitude generally these days ... I got my answer so I stop arguing.

Comment: My first comment gave you the possible answer, then I closed, and immediately asked if it helped. Now, my question: if Georgery hadn't posted the answer, and you read through the linked post, would it help you to understand the issue and lead you towards a solution? Also, where exactly do you see "hostility"?

Comment: @zx8754 - sorry the hostility bit was more a general statement not applying to you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x_value <- factor("yes", levels = c("no", "yes"))
df <- data.frame(
    x = x_value
)

df

    x
1 yes
```

**Why the example in the question is showing this "weird" behaviour**:

The dataframe created has a factor with one level. The corresponding number of that level is one, and this is the element that is associated with, when you set `levels()`.

Here is a quick example:

If we create a dataframe like this

```
x_value <- c("somethingElse", "more", "more")
df <- data.frame(
    x = x_value
)

df$x
```

shows us that the levels are

```
[1] somethingElse more          more         
Levels: more somethingElse
```

Note, that the first level is `"more"` even though `"somethingElse"` occurs first. This is because when sorted `"more"`comes first.
So, if we assign now

```
levels(df$x) <- c("yes", "somethingElse", "more")
```

the first factor level gets `"yes"`, the second gets `"somethingElse"`, resulting in (maybe unintuitively)

```
              x
1 somethingElse
2           yes
3           yes
```